# why gzip file size varies each time?

Tags: gzip

When i am taring and gzipping a folder, each time i am getting a different file size.

The contents of the directory is same and not changed. The compressed file size changes by 20 to 100 bytes. Is this a normal behavior?

Does my data will get affected with this?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you added the previous .tgz to the archive?

Comment: Interesting. Did you diff the attempts?

Comment: maybe some timestamps on the folder changes the compression descisions

Comment: I am sure that the .tgz files are not adding again. not sure about the timestamp

Comment: Anyone found out why this happened? happened to my files before too.

Comment: How big was you file ?

Answer (score 0):

tar generates a different file each time (check with md5sum), the reason is ordering is different. i guess gzip is affected by ordering.

yes, gzip should be affected by different ordering on the tar file, it's dictionary size is much smaller than the filesize.
and it should differ every time, after all each tar file is different!  (with the same contents)